# Use camelCase for OData WebAPI query string options?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'd like to use camelCase in my OData query like this

```
/api/posts?$filter=someProperty eq 1
```

instead of PascalCase like so

```
/api/posts?$filter=SomeProperty eq 1
```

Is that possible? (Without changing the casing of my C# classes of course.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally this feature now is supported in `Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 for OData v4.0` `v5.4.0`. You can install it via nuget [`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.OData -Pre`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/5.4.0-rc) and enable case insensitive:

```
config.EnableCaseInsensitive(true);
```

More info [here](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/case-insensitive/).

Answer (score 0):

No. OData properties are case sensitive. However there is a codeplex issue open to support case insensitive property names for OData queries in web API [here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/366). Vote for it if you think it should be supported.

Comment: I noticed that one of the comments on the codeplex issue you cited mentioned that "$orderby [PropertyName] DESC" doesn't work but "$orderby [PropertyName] desc" does.  I guess the OData is very strict, for now at least...